# Easiest way to parse a triple nested JSON?

Tags: java, json, parsing

I am given a JSON that will come in this format:

```
   "template":{  
      "mod1":[  
         {  
            "param1":"55",
            "param2":"5",
            "param3":"somedata"
         }
      ],
      "mod2":[  
         {  
            "param1":"somedata",
            "param2":"somedata"
         }
      ],
      "mod3":[  
         {  
            "param1":"somedata",
            "param2":"somedata",
            "param3":"somedata"
         }
      ],
      "mod4":[  
         {  
            "param1":"somedata",
            "param2":"somedata"
         }
      ],
      "mod5":[  
         {  
            "param1":"somedata"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

What is the easiest way to parse it? What I'd like is to get the params inside the mod and their associated values together, to store into a database. The way I am doing it is as so:

```
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);
    System.out.println(obj);
    Iterator<String> keys = obj.keys();
    while(keys.hasNext()) {
        String key = keys.next();
        JSONObject currTemplate = (JSONObject) obj.get(key);
        if(currTemplate instanceof JSONObject) {
            System.out.println("LIST OF ALL MODULES : " + currTemplate);
            Iterator<String> currObjKeys = ((JSONObject) currTemplate).keys();
            while(currObjKeys.hasNext()) {
                String currObjKey = currObjKeys.next();
                System.out.println("MODULE: " + currObjKey);
                JSONArray array = currTemplate.getJSONArray(currObjKey);
                System.out.println("ARRAY: " + array);
                for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++){
                JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
                String[] names = JSONObject.getNames(object);
                for(String name: names) {
                    System.out.println("PARAMS");
                    System.out.println(name);
                    System.out.println(object.get(name));
                }
                }
            }
        }
```

And it currently prints what I need correctly. What I am asking is if there is a more efficient way to do it - the way I currently have it is O(N^4), and I was wondering if anyone had any idea to parse the JSON in a more efficient way. Note: the params will not always be in form param1, param2, the names will always be different. Just changed it for confidentiality sake.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you doing it for your own understanding or are you going to implementing it in an application. If you are creating an application, I will suggest using gson for the same.
https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.5/com/google/gson/Gson.html#fromJson-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-

Comment: For my own application. I will look into GSON

Comment: i will say go for `Map` at each level